# Facebook Login Button won't respond anymore

Tags: android, facebook

The first time my application starts, when I press the Facebook Login button a popup shows up asking permission to allow profile access.

After I press Cancel, when I press again the Facebook login button nothing happens. I even pressed it multiple times but the popup never shows again.

I am using Facebook SDK for Android 3.0.